# TDD with mocha and mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, ruby-mocha

I'm trying to add mongodb via Mongo Ruby Driver to my sinatra app, and I've decided to so it the right way. When I started to think about TDD I coudn't find any examples or guidance about how to do it with mongodb.

After some time I started to think that I should use mocha for my unit tests with mongodb. But I thought I would double check with the community. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use mocha or any other mocking framework... It doesn't make a difference if you're doing it with ActiveRecord, Mongoid, DM, since the behavior will be mocked. Anyway, that's my thoughts..